# Avoiding double caching of items available from different URIs using Varnish

Tags: regex, caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

In the Varnish Cache wiki it states an example of how to `regsub` to avoid caching request to www.example.com and example.com separately. The example from https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/RedirectsAndRewrites is:

```
set req.http.host = regsub(req.http.host, "^www\.example\.com$","example.com");
```

"Requests to www.example.com and example.com will all go to the backend as "example.com" and end up cached by that string." This means duplicate caching does not occur.

I have multiple sites using the same varnish server (VCL) so am looking to replace "example.com" with a statement that will work on multiple URLs. eg:

```
www.example1.co.uk > example1.co.uk
www.example2.com > example2.com
```

What would be the appropriate regex (if that is the correct term) for this?

There are multiple separate domains (different sites with different content on different domains) using this VCL I am hoping to avoid having to alter the vcl when new sites are added/removed. Therefore a generic solution is what I am after, something that can be applied to any domain to remove the possibility of a duplicate with/without the WWW alias being store/served by Varnish. (Having trouble phrasing this, hope it is clearer!!)

I am aware that redirecting can be done outside of varnish, in Apache etc, but not looking for that as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
set req.http.host = regsub(req.http.host,
                           "^www\.(.*)$",
                           "\1");
```

This will strip www off any domain. (I do feel reluctant to give you this answer, as it goes against my [religion](http://www.yes-www.org/))

You might get penalized by search engines for serving the same content on multiple URLs, but SEO is a different topic.

Comment: thanks. I do not think I explained the question properly. As there are multiple sites I do not want to have to name the domain, just apply a generic rule which will apply to any requests. i.e. not have 'example' in the solution. I will try to clarify the question.

Comment: @TaylorTaff, I've adjusted the answer. Please adjust the question.

Comment: Thanks that looks great! Question adjusted. As it is against your religion (I agree with you!), how would you go about adding 'www' to every request? I will test in a short while and then mark as correct.

Comment: @TaylorTaff Check the [redirection page](http://www.yes-www.org/redirection/) on that www.yes-www.org site. Redirecting will solve serving the same content on multiple URLs issue too.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of what Chris suggested, you can just remove the www part:

```
set req.http.host = regsub(req.http.host, "^www\.", "");
```

Should be a teeny tiny bit faster, too